# Difference between compiled version and downloaded?

Tags: workflow

Is there any advantages If I compile blender from source by default then download it. Faster build? Faster render? More stable? Etc?
Thx =)

Comment: @someonewithpc I'm not sure if it's totally off-topic. The OP is asking *why* build blender, not *how* to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The main reasons to build blender yourself are:

- If you build from the latest sources, you get the very newest features. You'll also get the latest bugs, so save early and often, and keep the bug tracker open ;)
- You can apply patches such as [this one](https://developer.blender.org/T38401), and get features which aren't even in the official sources yet.

There are also some hardware-specific [optimization tricks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) you can do depending on your [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers), but these can potentially make blender unstable. Also see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Attic:Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu_Feisty_Fawn#Blender_optimization_on_ubuntu.2Fsimilar_distros).

Comment: You could also add as a bullet point that one could gets the latest bugs ;-)

Comment: Thx a lot man  -))

Comment: @user2439 if you compile for your own architecture, you don't need backwards compatibility, which might run faster